# Software acceleration slows App

Tags: java, android

I have a custom view which draws me a Candlestick chart in onDraw method.
So, on version 4.4 of android it's not properly draws some of sticks(missing rects, lines). It's known bug of a hardware acceleration on >4.0 or something like that versions of android. If i use    LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, i get a lot of lags and slowdown of app.

If there a proper way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: I read this article, but cannot figure out where is my mistake with drawing primitives.

Comment: Solved through bitmap